# Why would the sequence $\hat{x}_{n+1} = \left( A^T E(\hat{x}_n) A\right)^{-1} A^T E(\hat{x}_n)b$ from Least absolut deviation regression converge

Tags: least-absolute-deviations

Consider the problem

$$
\min_x f(x) = \min_x \|b - Ax\|_{1} = \min_x \sum_i \left| b_i - \sum_j a_{ij}x_{j} \right|
$$
where $x,b$ are vectors and $A$ matrix of some dimension.

Then
$$
\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial x_k} = \sum_i \frac{b_i - \sum_j a_{ij}x_j}{\left|b_i - \sum_j a_{ij}x_j \right|} (-a_{ik}) = 0 \Rightarrow \\
\sum_i \frac{a_{ik}b_i}{\epsilon_i(x)} = \sum_i \sum_j \frac{a_{ik}a_{ij}x_{j}}{\epsilon_i(x)}
$$
where $\epsilon_i = \left|b_i - \sum_j a_{ij}x_j \right|$
or in matrix notation

$$
A^TE(x)b = A^T E(x) Ax
$$

where $E(x) = \text{Diag}(\epsilon(x))^{-1}$.

Assuming that $ A^T E(x) A$ is invertible, define

$$
\hat{x}_{n+1} = \left( A^T E(\hat{x}_n) A\right)^{-1} A^T E(\hat{x}_n)b
$$

The claim is now that for a given initial point $x_0$, $x = \lim_n x_n$ will solve $\min_x \|b - Ax\|_{1}$.

How is this true? Can it be proven from Banach fix point theorem?

The claim can be found here https://vanderbei.princeton.edu/542/lectures/lec9.pdf
on slide 11 and 12 without proof.

Comment: I realize you're quoting directly from the slides, but first they need to be fixed, because the matrix multiplication in the iteration make no sense: the dimensions are all wrong.  If $Ax$ makes sense as a matrix product, then so does $AE(x),$ but--unless $A$ is square--the expression $A^\prime E(x)$ is nonsense.  The preliminaries are also troubling insofar as the function isn't everywhere differentiable but it is being treated as if it is.  BTW, the notation "$E(\hat x_n)$" is horrible because to almost anyone reading this post it will be understood as an *expectation!*

Comment: Assume dimensions $b :N \times 1, \ x: M \times 1, \ A:  N \times M$ Then $E(x)$ will have dimension $N \times N$ so $A^TE(x)$ will have dimension $M \times N$ and $A^TE(x)A$ will have dimension $M \times M$. Maybe I messed up some indexation... To my understanding we only consider it for the points where it is differentiable. @whuber

Comment: I see--the notation is tremendously confusing, because it's hard not to read $E(x)$ as having dimension $M\times M.$  I don't think you messed up anything--I realize you're just quoting the slides.